# How to check if a subscription has been cancelled?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have requested a refund on my own app’s monthly subscription.  Apple gave me the refund.  But my subscription is still active and I can use the premium features.

My app is checking the validity of the receipt every time I use it, this proves that the receipt's expiry date has remained valid.

This is how I check for it. Although it is in Python on my server, I hope the code is clear enough for anyone to understand:

```
def verify_receipt(receipt):
    r = requests.post(config.APPLE_STORE_URL, json=Subscription.produce_receipt_with_credentials(receipt))
    now = datetime.utcnow()
    if 'latest_receipt_info' in r.json():
        for item in r.json()['latest_receipt_info']:
            dt, tz = item['expires_date'].rsplit(maxsplit=1)
            expires_date = datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone(tz))
            expires_date = expires_date.astimezone(pytz.utc)
            expires_date = expires_date.replace(tzinfo=None)
            if expires_date > now:
                return True, expires_date, r.json()['latest_receipt'], item
    else:
        current_app.logger.info('latest_receipt_info not found: %s', r.json())
    return False, None, None, None
```

Essentially I'm checking within the collection of ‘latest_receipt_info’ for each receipt's ‘expires_date’. If at least one of them is set in the future, then the premium check is valid.

But in my case even though that Apple has refunded the subscription, they left it active until the next renewal.

> So what is the point of checking the receipt regularly then? If we
>   can't catch early cancellation?

Wouldn’t be more efficient and faster for the existing users to just save the expiry date in UserDefaults and check locally when the expiry date has expired and **then** check for the validity of the next receipt?

**SWIFT:**

`UserDefaults.standard.set(expiryDate, forKey: Constants.expiryDate)`

**UPDATE:**

So based on the answer I have received, I suppose the `cancellation_reason` and `cancellation_date` will be next to these fields in the latest receipt?

```
"latest_receipt_info": [
    {
      "quantity": "1",
      "product_id": "com.x.sub.weekly",
      "transaction_id": "100000053x",
      "original_transaction_id": "100000053x",
      "purchase_date": "2019-06-03 19:52:05 Etc/GMT",
      "purchase_date_ms": "1559591525000",
      "purchase_date_pst": "2019-06-03 12:52:05 America/Los_Angeles",
      "original_purchase_date": "2019-06-03 19:52:06 Etc/GMT",
      "original_purchase_date_ms": "1559591526000",
      "original_purchase_date_pst": "2019-06-03 12:52:06 America/Los_Angeles",
      "expires_date": "2019-06-03 19:55:05 Etc/GMT",
      "expires_date_ms": "1559591705000",
      "expires_date_pst": "2019-06-03 12:55:05 America/Los_Angeles",
      "web_order_line_item_id": "10000000x",
      "is_trial_period": "false",
      "is_in_intro_offer_period": "false"
      "cancellation_reason": "0", 
      "cancellation_date" "2019-06-03 21:55:05 Etc/GMT"
    },
```

I wished there was a way to emulate this. How can I code against this based on the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW1) and go to production without being really able to test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For refunds you need to check the `cancellation_reason` field which will indicate that customer support refunded the user. There will also be a `cancellation_date` that will indicate when the cancellation occurred.

If that field is present then your premium check should be invalid:

> Treat a canceled receipt the same as if no purchase had ever been
>   made.

Comment: That's a great answer, thank you. So the `cancellation_reason` will be "0" or "1", if it's cancelled, but nil if it wasn't cancelled? And only then check `cancellation_date` secondarily. Because the latter can still happen if the user upgrades the sub, which doesn't mean that it was actually cancelled.  Is there a way to emulate this? Otherwise, I have to code this based on docs and go to production. It's quite risky :( Thanks

Comment: Oh, by the way, I have updated the question to illustrate what I meant. Thanks

Comment: Upgrades don't work on sandbox so you wouldn't be able to test `cancellation_date` :/ If you have the full payload in your prod logs somewhere you may be able to emulate it. The `cancellation_reason` should only be present on refunds.

Comment: Thanks I could try to inject a check into my production to save the payload for my username and take it from there. :-). So hacky. I can't believe this Apple doesn't provide a better way to test this.